# MySQL controlling filtering data from table using booleans from another table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have 4 tables in my database, a top layer followed by the other three, each one a layer deeper in terms of logic, linked via foreign keys.
4 booleans on the top layer control which rows should get selected in the second lowest level.
The result I am trying to achieve is getting the correct data based on these booleans, as well as a count of the lowest layer.

All tables and columns have been renamed for this example.
The booleans are (in this example) type_filter_1, type_filter_2, type_filter_3, type_filter_4. The naming of these booleans have nothing to do with the table names, they are internally linked with a string value in the `level_2` table. These strings are imported from an Excel file

Table level_4 (top layer) as no direct connections

```
Columns:
    - id
    - name
    - type_filter_1
    - type_filter_2
    - type_filter_3
    - type_filter_4
    ...
```

Table level_3 (second layer) has a direct connection to level_4

```
Columns:
    - id
    - level_4_id
    - name
    ...
```

Table level_2 (third layer) has a direct connection to level_4

```
Columns:
    - id
    - level_4_id
    ...
```

Table level_1 (bottom layer) has a direct connection to level_2 and level_3

```
Columns:
    - id
    - level_2_id
    - level_3_id
    ...
```

The query so far is:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT level_1.id) AS DP_ADDRESSES_COUNT,
    level_4.*,
    level_4.id AS id
FROM
    `level_4`
    LEFT JOIN `level_3` ON `level_3`.`level_4_id` = `level_4`.`id`
    LEFT JOIN `level_1` ON `level_1`.`level_3` = `level_3`.`id`
    LEFT JOIN `level_2` ON `level_1`.`level_2_id` = `level_2`.`id`
WHERE
    `level_4`.`id` = '4'
    AND CASE WHEN level_4.type_filter_1 = 0 THEN
        level_2.type != "KEY_1"
    ELSE
        TRUE
    END
    OR CASE WHEN level_4.type_filter_2 = 0 THEN
        level_2.type != "KEY_2"
    ELSE
        TRUE
    END
    OR CASE WHEN level_4.type_filter_3 = 0 THEN
        level_2.type != "KEY_3"
    ELSE
        TRUE
    END
    OR CASE WHEN level_4.type_filter_4 = 0 THEN
        level_2.type NOT IN("KEY_4", "KEY_5")
    ELSE
        TRUE
    END
GROUP BY
    `level_4`.`id`
LIMIT 1;
```

Any help with this query will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Any time you find yourself with enumerated column names, consider whether your schema design is optimal

Comment: @strawberry these values are part of a large Excel import. Using foreign kets to another table for example won’t improve the situation by a lot...

Comment: A normalised schema will improve the situation *a lot*.